# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: sessionInjectorProvider

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive, loopbackjs

I am new to angular js, loopback and nodejs,

While implementing the authentication in the angular app, I am getting the below mentioned error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: sessionInjectorProvider <- sessionInjector <- $http <- $compile
```

I was going through this document, but no help. 
http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

This error came when I added the below lines for sessionInjector

```
angular.module('myApp', []).factory('sessionInjectorProvider', ['SessionService', function(SessionService) {
    var sessionInjector = {
        request: function(config) {
            if (!SessionService.isAnonymus) {
                config.headers['x-session-token'] = SessionService.token;
            }
            return config;
        }
    };
    return sessionInjector;
}]);

angular.module('myApp', []).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
}]);
```

Comment: Every time you do `angular.module('myApp', [])` module is newly created and anything registered to that module previously are gone. probably you may want to do `angular.module('myApp').config..` Also `sessionInjectorProvider` must be injected into the interceptor as `sessionInjectorProvider`

Comment: So try `angular.module('myApp').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjectorProvider');
}]);`

Comment: did both the changes still getting the same issue.

Comment: Try to replicate this error in a plunker.. It should not be hard, its just 2 blocks.. You will get the clue yourself

Answer (score 0):

There are for sure at least two errors in your code:

`angular.module('myApp', [])` creates a module, whereas `angular.module('myApp')` calls the module. This means that at the end of your code you're creating again the module and hence losing what you had written before.

There are different ways to format this code, one that would solve the problem would be:

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .factory('sessionInjectorProvider', ['SessionService', function(SessionService) {
            var sessionInjector = {
                request: function(config) {
                    if (!SessionService.isAnonymus) {
                config.headers['x-session-token'] = SessionService.token;
                    }
                    return config;
                }
            };
            return sessionInjector;
        }])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
                    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjectorProvider');
        }]);
```

Also, as mentioned already, you're mixing 'sessionInjectorProvider' and 'sessionInjector' - your interceptor should use 'sessionInjectorProvider' as shown in the code I posted above.